# Why is my recursive search function not working?

Tags: python, recursion

I need to write a simple recursive function that searches through an array from the index: left to index: right. We don't have to worry about invalid left and right inputs, which are always correct. If there is a value in the array equal to the key, it returns the index of that value. If the key isn't in the array, it returns `-1.`
I really don't know why my function doesn't work. I think it should. It only works if the key is the first index of the array.

```py
def binary_search_recursive(array: List[int], left: int, right: int,
                            key: int) -> int:
    if left <= right:
        if array[left] == key:
            return left
        else:
            binary_search_recursive(array, left + 1, right, key)
    return -1
```

Test:

```py
binary_search_recursive([0,1,5,6,23,45], 0, 5, 5)
```

Should return:

```py
2
```

Returns:

```py
-1
```

Comment: Your else-branch should `return binary_search_recursive(...)`. It should return whatever the recursive call returns.

Comment: That's not a binary search. That's a binary search that uses recursion to enumerate over every element.

Comment: Yeah, it's called linear search when you are going element by element unless you find it. In binary search, you search half the list then half of that half, and so on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your code, you need to return the else statement :

```
def binary_search_recursive(array: list[int], left: int, right: int,
                            key: int) -> int:
    if left <= right:
        if array[left] == key:
            return left
        else:
            return binary_search_recursive(array, left + 1, right, key)
    return -1
```

But still, it is not a binary search.

**EDIT:** A real binary search would be some thing like below:

```
def binary_search_recursive(array: list[int], left: int, right: int,
                            key: int) -> int:
    if right >= left:

        center = (right + left) // 2

        if array[center] == key:
            return center

        elif array[center] > key:
            return binary_search_recursive(array, left, center - 1, key)
        else:
            return binary_search_recursive(array, center + 1, right, key)
    return -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the result of the recursive call to `binary_search_recursive()`:

```py
binary_search_recursive(array, left + 1, right, key)
```

should be

```py
return binary_search_recursive(array, left + 1, right, key)
```

Note that this is *not* a binary search algorithm; you're enumerating one element at a time (using recursion), so this is really a sequential search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tab in the second return. Try:

```
                            key: int) -> int:
    if left <= right:
        if array[left] == key:
            return left
        else:
            binary_search_recursive(array, left + 1, right, key)
            return -1 #Moved to the right.
```

Comment: Doesn't fix. Still returns -1